# Cannot change text to image use preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I am trying to convert the texts in a string to emoticons. I have tried and succeeded half way.

Problem:
When i am replacing the characters in the string to emoticons, characters such as ":/" in a link http://mywebsite.com also gets replaced.

What i did till now:

chat.php

```
<?php 
require('common.php');
if($_POST && !empty($_POST['title'])){
    $result = $db->add_news($_POST['title']);
}
$text="";
function parseSmiley($text){
    //Smiley to image
    $smileys=array('o:)'=>'angel.gif', ':3'=>'colonthree.gif', 'o.O'=>'confused.gif', ":'("=>'cry.gif', '3:)'=>'devil.gif', ':('=>'frown.gif', ':O'=>'gasp.gif', '8)'=>'glasses.gif', ':D'=>'grin.gif', ">:-("=>'grumpy.gif', '<3'=>'heart.gif', '^_^'=>'kiki.gif', ':*'=>'kiss.gif', ':v'=>'pacman.gif', ':)'=>'smile.gif', '-_-'=>'squint.gif', '8|'=>'sunglasses.gif', ':p'=>'tongue.gif', ':/'=>'unsure.gif', '>:-O'=>'upset.gif', ';)'=>'wink.gif');

    //Now you need to find and replace
    foreach($smileys as $smiley=>$img){
        $text=str_replace(htmlspecialchars($smiley), "<img src='emotions-fb/{$img}'/>", $text);
    }
    //Now only return it
    return $text;
}
?>
```

db.php

```
function get_news(){
    if($result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE id<>1 ORDER BY add_date DESC LIMIT 50')){
        $return = '';
        while($r = $result->fetch_object()){
            $timing=explode(" ", $r->add_date);

            $return .= '<p>'.wordwrap(htmlspecialchars($r->title), 25, "\n", true).'</p>';
            //$return .='<p>'.$timing[1].' on '.$timing[0].'</p>';
            $return .= '<hr/>';
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
```

After that I searched on stackoverflow and got something like this but this doesnt replace any text to image

```
    foreach($smileys as $smiley=>$img){
        $smiley=preg_quote($smiley);
        $text=preg_replace("~\b$smiley\b~", "<img src='emotions-fb/{$img}'/>", $text);

    }
```

I dont know where I am going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$smileys=array('o:)'=>'angel.gif', ':3'=>'colonthree.gif', 'o.O'=>'confused.gif', ":'("=>'cry.gif', '3:)'=>'devil.gif', ':('=>'frown.gif', ':O'=>'gasp.gif', '8)'=>'glasses.gif', ':D'=>'grin.gif', ">:-("=>'grumpy.gif', '<3'=>'heart.gif', '^_^'=>'kiki.gif', ':*'=>'kiss.gif', ':v'=>'pacman.gif', ':)'=>'smile.gif', '-_-'=>'squint.gif', '8|'=>'sunglasses.gif', ':p'=>'tongue.gif', ':/'=>'unsure.gif', '>:-O'=>'upset.gif', ';)'=>'wink.gif');
$text='Some example text with smile :/ ^_^ and :\'( and link <a href="http://google.com"> my site :/</a>';
foreach ($smileys as $smiley => $img)
{
    $smiley = preg_quote( $smiley );
    $text = preg_replace( "#(?<=\s|^)(?:$smiley)(?=\s|$)?#i", '<img src="emotions-fb/'. $img .'">', $text);
}
echo $text;
```

Comment: Nopes. Doesnt work. It gives warning,  compilation failed:unmatched paranthesis at offset 9

Comment: I tested only for one smile: :/ and it works. Edit my answer for all smileys. What version of php do you have? Check it: http://ideone.com/aNr7Ut

Comment: I tried by downloading the file you gave but it still gives me warning: nothing to repeat at offset ... On line 8
I am using php 5.3.13

Comment: I use 5.3.28 on both testes machine and it work. Try `$smiley = preg_quote( $smiley, '/' );`

Comment: Try: `$text = preg_replace( "#(?<=\s|^)(?:$smiley)((?=\s|$))?#i", '<img src="emotions-fb/'. $img .'">', $text);`

Comment: should i use this without the preg_quote part?

Comment: ok, now it works but it with a defined text but doesnt show anything when i return the values from db.php to chat.php

Comment: `var_dump( on_values_from_db );`

Comment: where should i place this?

Comment: If everything is ok with defined text, something wrong must be with text from database right?

Comment: umm..but i am getting correct values returned from the database. Am i doing something wrong while passing the values?? see my code above.